# Create Test Area on website built with Expression Engine

Tags: expressionengine

i have to make some updates to a web site built using expression engine.  There is no staging area available so i'd like to create a test area of the web site accessible only to site owners allowing them to preview the changes.

Ordinarily, i'd just create a "test" folder and direct the users to this URL.  I'm new to Expression Engine and not sure how to achieve this.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a new template group and templates (e.g., "section_test"), direct them there to preview, and then change the template/group names to the proper names once you're ready to launch.

As an additional layer of security, you can add HTTP authentication to this test template.

Answer (score 0):

For previewing CSS changes, I added this to the  of my templates:

```
{if group_title=="Super Admins"}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/design/style-dev.css" />
{if:else}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/design/style.css" />
{/if}
```

If the test section is a particular channel, in the control panel you can set the permissions on the channel so that only a particular group can view it.

If you regularly need to preview pages before they go live, consider creating a new status, like "preview". By default, EE only shows items where the status is open. You can specify which statuses are shown like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries weblog="myPages" status="open|preview"}
    {if status == "preview"}
        {if group_title == "Super Admins"}
            <p>the title is {title}</p>
        {/if}
    {/if}
    <p>the title is {title}</p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This example uses nested conditionals instead of a conditional with an AND in it, because conditionals with ANDs are considered complex and are parsed differently. (Look up complex conditionals to learn more.)

You have to repeat all the display code within the entries tag pair, so consider using an embed or a snippet for the repeated code.